xdebug not installed on php 8.3 docker container
I'm using this Dockerfile
FROM php:8.3-apache

RUN pecl install xdebug-3.3.2 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd pdo pdo_mysql zip

RUN echo "xdebug.mode=debug" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.start_with_request=yes" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

RUN a2enmod rewrite

EXPOSE 9003

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY apache-config.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]

when I check phpinfo() I see that xdebug is no t installed, the same Dockerfile with
FROM php:8.1-apache

RUN pecl install xdebug-3.1.1 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

works  with no problems
I checked on xdebug web and xdebug 3.3.2 is compatible with php 8.3

What is your exact PHP 8.3 version?

php 8.3.11 @LajosArpad

What is the output if you do "docker compose up" - there is likely a warning or error.
